# Using the youtube analytics api or youtube data api, is there a way to get the video from a channel with the most comments?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been trying for some days now by reading the docs to figure out how to use any of the two APIs mentioned in the title to retrieve a channel's most commented video.

This query doesn't work:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?ids=channel==MINE&dimensions=video&metrics=comments&maxResults=1&sort=-comments&startDate=2022-07-12&endDate=2022-09-12'
```

But querying for the same dimension but for the views metric instead works:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?ids=channel==MINE&dimensions=video&metrics=views&maxResults=1&sort=-views&startDate=2022-07-12&endDate=2022-09-12'
```

One weird thing is that even though the documentation specifies that ascending order sorting is working by default (Docs: `A comma-separated list of dimensions or metrics that determine the sort order for YouTube Analytics data. By default the sort order is ascending. The - prefix causes descending sort order.` ) you can't run some requests without specifically using descending order. For example the views request above.

But changing the sort parameter to `sort=view` (Ascending) results in the following response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v2/available_reports for a list of supported queries.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v2/available_reports for a list of supported queries.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And removing the sort parameter has the same result.

Anyone knows how to solve this mystery with the youtube analytics api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) endpoints you can get the most commented video on a given channel.

Indeed by:

1. fetching all video ids from the channel by using [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with `part=snippet` and `playlistId=UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID` where `UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID` is the channel id with its second character (`C`) replaced by `U`.
2. pass all these video ids to [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with `part=statistics`
3. sort on your side all the video `commentCount`s

Comment: I'll try this out! And come back with my findings, thank you very much.

Comment: Already tried this and it's looking good so far! Thank you very much. One additional question, do you know if there's a limit to the amount of IDs I can pass to the videos endpoint ?

Comment: You can provide up to 50 `id`s according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#maxResults). Mind [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem.